# Parent or master business card document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, master-page

I have 50 or so business cards to make and they all have the same design and layout with only the text details changing (names, titles, etc).  Is there a way to set up a parent or 'master page' type document that contains the master design with all the individual business cards linked to this parent document.  When the font style or colour or size or layout or whatever is changed on the parent document then it will automatically be applied across the 50 business cards.  Does anyone know a way to do this in Illustrator or Indesign.

Comment: Hi user58694, yes you will want to use InDesign. You will be working with master pages, character styles and paragraph styles. I voted to close your question as your question is either too broad or asking for basic software education.

Comment: Yeah, this is an inDesign-101 question.In addition to the terms above, consider "linking indd document"

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in Illustrator.

You just make one business card and write a script that changes the name and exports out a printable copy, then changes the name to the next one on the list and exports out a printable copy, and so on.

The advantage is you don’t have to make 50 pages in InDesign, and this would also scale to 10,000 names if you like.

If using AppleScript, you can pull the names from a database.